# python - remove all char after the latest occurency of \

Tags: python

I have this string:

```
fulldir = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\P_backup\EVENTSERVICE\CPD"
```

How can I remove only the `"\CPD"`, I want to remove all after my last "\".

p.s python script written in python 3.7.2

can you help me?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `os.path.split` function:

```
import os
fulldir = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\P_backup\EVENTSERVICE\CPD"
res = os.path.split(fulldir)[0]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\P_backup\EVENTSERVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `rindex(substring)` to get the last index of where the substring occurs, then splice it from the beginning to that index (plus one so that you include the substring '\')

```
fulldir = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\P_backup\EVENTSERVICE\CPD"
print(fulldir)
fulldir = fulldir[0:fulldir.rindex('\\')+1]
print(fulldir)
```

Comment: will recommend to use `rfind` if you want to go to that way. So that it handles the case where there is no '\' present in the string